# ms sql добавить в таблицу и взять данные

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте не могу после добавлении в таблицу взять данные поля.
есть таблица для с которой надо сделать два. В одну данные залить о почте и взять оттуда Id после по этому Id закинуть остальные данные имя, фамилия и т.д. в другую таблицу. Помогите пожалуйста в sql не очень силен.

Comment: `в sql не очень силен`. Как и в русском. Прочитайте внимательно то, что написали в вопросе и сформулируйте его правильно, иначе он может быть интерпретирован некорректно.

Comment: Если правильно понял, то пишите в одну таблицу. Потом   получаете последний вставленный id, в зависимости от вашей СУБД, например для mysql его возвращает функция last_insert_id(). Можно эту функцию использовать прямо при вставке записи во вторую таблицу

Comment: не совсем есть два Id который GUID и мой INT мне нужен он

Comment: Укажите в тегах, какую именно СУБД используете. Приведите схемы используемых таблиц (`create table ...`).

Comment: ms sql, проект на asp.net core code first